# MVC 3 DropDownListFor: Cannot figure out 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' cannot be serialized

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, serialization, drop-down-menu

I cannot figure out how to do serialization with a DropDownList and am getting the error "**Type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' cannot be serialized.**" I am using serialization in a wizard form to persist the user inputs through the end and then to post a confirmation.

I am using the following in a view:

```
@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost())
{ 
    @Html.Hidden("myData", new MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed))
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RealEstate, Model.RealEstateList)
    ...
}
```

In my ViewModel (MyData), I have:

```
[Serializable]
public class myData
{
public int RealEstate { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RealEstateList { get; set; }
...
public MyData()
    {
        var realestatelist = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "(Please select)" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text="Some text." },                
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text="Some other text." }
            };
        this.RealEstateList = new SelectList(realestatelist, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SelectList does not support serialization. Try to use `IEnumerable<SelectedListItem>`,  `IList<SelectListItem>` or `List<SelectedListItem>` in your controller and then create the SelectList in the view.

Change controller similar to this:

```
public MyData()
    {
        var realestatelist = new List<SelectListItem>() {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "(Please select)" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text="Some text." },                
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text="Some other text." }
            };
        this.RealEstateList = realestatelist;
    }
}
```

And seeing your `RealEstateList` in the model is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` you can make the SelectList in the view then to specify the value and text without converting the model property like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RealEstate, new SelectList(Model.RealEstateList, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: I was using the @Html code you posted and still getting the error which is what was driving me mad. The SIMPLE solution was to change my code `this.RealEstateList = new SelectList(realestatelist, "Value", "Text");` to yours **`this.RealEstateList = realestatelist;`** THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectList` class can't be serialized, as the error is saying. If you need to serialize a set of `SelectListItem` objects you'll need to use a container that can be serialized, like a `List<SelectListItem>`.

You will need to convert your `List<SelectListItem>` back into a `SelectList` inside your view, like:

```
@{
    var bindList = new SelectList(Model.RealEstateList);
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RealEstate, bindList)
```