# Unable to serialize List<SelectListItem>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm moving an existing MVC3 app from InProc to ASP.Net Session State service.
One of the model objects has this property:

```
public List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> StateCodes { get; set; }
```

and it's throwing this error

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

Is there a way to get `List<SelectListItem>` to serialize?

Comment: Copy the values to a new List(e.g. List<string>) and serialize it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC 3 DropDownListFor: Cannot figure out 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' cannot be serialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214918/mvc-3-dropdownlistfor-cannot-figure-out-system-web-mvc-selectlist-cannot-be-s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to create the select list items in the Razor code instead by with a `SelectList`. Let the model instead have a property for the underlying data that the `SelectList` is based on. You may also try to place the `SelectList` in the `ViewBag` or `ViewData`, that could also solve problem.

Storing `SelectList`'s in the view model is regarded as bad practice.

Comment: why is it bad practice? Because the view model shouldn't have information about the view's components?

Answer (score 3):

[Just adding some information to the answer above] I believe that

> Storing SelectList's in the view model is regarded as bad practice.

is due to the fact that the viewmodel shouldn't be builded in such a specific way about how the information will be shown to the final user.

If the viewmodel has a list of items, and the view renders a SelectList is fine of course. But the view could choose to present that data to the final user in many other ways.

Answer (score 2):

Bad practice aside, if converting to a different sesssion storage system and your code is littered with these and changing them out is not conducive to your timeframe, you can get by by marking your class as `[Serializable]` and then changing all your members that are list of selectlist items to the following:

```
namespace blah.blah.blah
[Serializable]
public class Blah : FromBlah

[NonSerialized]
private List<SelectListItem> _mySelectList;
public List<SelectListItem> MySelectList
{
    get { return _mySelectList; }
    set { _mySelectList= value; }
}
```

Also, adding the following terms for searchability for any people out there who got this issue after adding RedisSessionProvider, Redis, RedisSession, etc. You're welcome.